# How to apply filter at segment level while fetching content from json file

Tags: json, ionic2, navigation, segment

I am trying to fetch content from json file while moving from one segment to another in ionic 2 application. So the problem says, I have three segments 1. board, 2. grade, 3. mybooks, navigating to grade from seg1 to seg2 by selecting board it reached to seg2 screen successfully, now on clicking class 1 of seg2 i should reach to seg3 mybooks, with showing only class 1 books covers or display required content from json to seg3 filtering  on class basis. How can I achieve it Please help.

[image]
[image][image]

[image]

Code i have used for it:

```js
export class HomePage {
 Segments: string = "board"; // This is to set the tab content on the screen when its is opened.
 public posts: any;
 public board_icse: any;
  public board_cbse: any;
 public text: String;
  private barcodeText:String;
   private barcodeFormat:String;
   private platform:Platform;   
   private navController:NavController;
  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,platform:Platform, public http: Http) {
        this.platform = platform;
        this.navController = navCtrl;
  
  
  //this.http.get('/android_asset/www/assets/data/subjects.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(  //..for running on mobile..
    this.http.get('/assets/data/subjects.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(                //..for running on desktop
    response => {
        this.posts = response;
  
  this.board_cbse = response.filter(item => item.Board === 'CBSE');
  
  this.board_icse = response.filter(item => item.Board === 'ICSE');
  
  console.log("This is subjects from json file"+ this.posts);
  console.log("This is subjects from json file"+ this.board_cbse);
  console.log("This is subjects from json file"+ this.board_icse);
   },
    err => {
        console.log("Oops!");
    }); 
  
  
  
 }
 }
```

```html
  <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="Segments">
      <ion-segment-button value="board">
        <b>Select Board</b>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="grade">
        <b>Grade</b>
      </ion-segment-button>
   <ion-segment-button value="mycourses">
        <b>My Books</b>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>



<div [ngSwitch]="Segments">
    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'board'">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src="img/cbse.jpg">
        </ion-thumbnail>
  <ion-segment-button value="board1" (click)="Segments ='grade' " style="text-align: left !Important">
        <b>ICSE</b>
       </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src="img/icse.jpg">
        </ion-thumbnail>
       <ion-segment-button value="board2" (click)="Segments ='grade' " style="text-align: left !Important">
        <b>CBSE</b>
       </ion-segment-button>
      </ion-item>
     </ion-list>

 
   <ion-grid *ngSwitchCase="'grade'">
  
   <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
 <ion-segment-button value="garde1">
 <ion-card color="explore_grade">
    <ion-card-header>
    <p style="text-align: center; padding-top: 20%;" (click)="Segments ='mycourses'">Class 1</p>
    </ion-card-header>
 <ion-card-content>
    <!-- Add card content here! -->
   </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
 </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-col>
    
 <ion-col>
 <ion-segment-button value="garde1">
 <ion-card color="explore_grade">
    <ion-card-header>
    <p style="text-align: center; padding-top: 20%;" (click)="Segments ='mycourses'">Class 2</p>
    </ion-card-header>
 <ion-card-content>
    <!-- Add card content here! -->
  </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
 </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
 <ion-segment-button value="garde1">
 <ion-card color="explore_grade">
    <ion-card-header>
    <p style="text-align: center; padding-top: 20%;" (click)="Segments ='mycourses'">Class 3</p>
    </ion-card-header>
 <ion-card-content>
    <!-- Add card content here! -->
    </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
 </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-col>
    
 <ion-col>
 <ion-segment-button value="garde1">
     <ion-card color="explore_grade">
    <ion-card-header>
    <p style="text-align: center; padding-top: 20%;" (click)="Segments ='mycourses'">Class 4</p>
    </ion-card-header>
 <ion-card-content>
    <!-- Add card content here! -->
    </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
 </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
    <ion-segment-button value="garde1"> 
    <ion-card color="explore_grade">
    <ion-card-header>
    <p style="text-align: center; padding-top: 20%;" (click)="Segments ='mycourses'">Class 5</p>
    </ion-card-header>
 <ion-card-content>
    <!-- Add card content here! -->
    </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
 </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-col>
    
 <ion-col>
 <ion-segment-button value="garde1">
    <ion-card color="explore_grade">
    <ion-card-header>
    <p style="text-align: center; padding-top: 20%;" (click)="Segments ='mycourses'">Class 6</p>
    </ion-card-header>
 <ion-card-content>
    <!-- Add card content here! -->
    </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
 </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  

</ion-grid>  

  
 
<!-- This is showing tabs for the cbse grades  -->
<ion-list padding *ngSwitchCase="'mycourses'">
<ion-list *ngFor="let post of board_icse">
 <ion-card >

    <img src="img/{{post.src}}" />
    <ion-row no-padding>
      <!--<ion-col>
        <button ion-button clear small  icon-start>
          <ion-icon name='cart'></ion-icon>
          Add to cart
        </button>
      </ion-col> -->
      <ion-col text-center>
        <button ion-button clear small  icon-start>
          {{post.Name}}
        </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col text-right>
        <button ion-button clear small  icon-start (click)="scan()">
          Scan Bar code
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
 </ion-card>

</ion-list>

 
 


<ion-list *ngFor="let post of board_cbse">
 <ion-card >

    <img src="img/{{post.src}}" />
    <ion-row no-padding>
      <!--<ion-col>
        <button ion-button clear small  icon-start>
          <ion-icon name='cart'></ion-icon>
          Add to cart
        </button>
      </ion-col> -->
      <ion-col text-center>
        <button ion-button clear small  icon-start>
          {{post.Name}}
        </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col text-right>
        <button ion-button clear small  icon-start (click)="scan()">
          Scan Bar code
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
 </ion-card>

 </ion-list>
 
</ion-list>
 
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

**HTML File**

```
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'grade'">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src="img/class1.jpg">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <ion-segment-button value="class1" (click)="showBooksByClassName(1)" style="text-align: left !Important">
        <b>Class 1</b>
       </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-item>
       <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src="img/class2.jpg">
        </ion-thumbnail>
       <ion-segment-button value="class2" (click)="showBooksByClassName(2)" style="text-align: left !Important">
        <b>Class 2</b>
       </ion-segment-button>
      </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
```

**HomePage Class**

```
showBooksByClassName(classNumber: string) {

    let board = this.posts.filter(item => item.Board === 'ICSE');
    let booksCovers = board.filter(item => item.Class === classNumber); // Here you got book covers filterd data.
    this.Segments = "mycourses";
 }
```

I have pass static class number in `showBooksByClassName()` for demo you can make this dynamic.

also you have to create `<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'mycourses'"></ion-list>`
and show your book covers data.

Comment: thanks!!..but what if i have to select ICSE then Class 1, and CBSE then class 1, how do I have to retain selected board value, Because now we are keeping class name statically in function "showBooksByClassName()" then in script file filtering weather it is cbse or icse, can I filter or retain the board first then the value I can use further?

Comment: You have to pass another parameter of board name in `showBooksByClassName()` function like this `showBooksByClassName(classNmae, boardName)`.

Comment: Very thanks..!! for giving me right logic, its is done after making some modification in my code.

Comment: One more doubt @hrdisback, how could I display a message on html if it does not found any matching book.

Comment: I think you are storing books data in `this.board` object so you can use `*ngIf`. Add one more `<ion-row *ngIf="board == undefined || board.length == 0">No Books Found.</ion-row>`.

Answer (score 0):

so finally, how I achieve it by calling two function one on board to capture the board value and then on seg2 another function to capture the class name of that board and then displayed it in html file.

```js
showboard(boardName: string)
{
console.log("class name obtained "+ boardName);

this.Segments = "grade";

this.myboard = this.posts.filter(item => item.Board === boardName);
console.log("board obtained on clicking on board "+ this.myboard);
}

showBooksByClassName(classNumber: String) {
    
 console.log("class name obtained as parameter "+ classNumber);
 console.log("class myboard obtained from above function "+ this.myboard);
 
  this.board = this.myboard.filter(item => item.Class == classNumber);
 console.log("This is board from json file="+ this.board);

 
    this.Segments = "mycourses";
 }
```

```html
<ion-content>


<div [ngSwitch]="Segments">
    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'board'">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src="img/cbse.jpg">
        </ion-thumbnail>
  <ion-segment-button value="board1" (click)="showboard('ICSE')" style="text-align: left !Important">
        <b>ICSE</b>
       </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail item-start>
          <img src="img/icse.jpg">
        </ion-thumbnail>
       <ion-segment-button value="board2" (click)="showboard('CBSE')" style="text-align: left !Important">
        <b>CBSE</b>
       </ion-segment-button>
      </ion-item>
      
    </ion-list>

 
   <ion-grid *ngSwitchCase="'grade'">
  
   <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
 <ion-segment-button value="garde1" (click)="showBooksByClassName('1')">
 <ion-card color="explore_grade">
    <ion-card-header>
    <p style="text-align: center; padding-top: 20%;">Class 1</p>
    </ion-card-header>
 <ion-card-content>
    <!-- Add card content here! -->
   </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
 </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-col>
    
 <ion-col>
 <ion-segment-button value="garde1" (click)="showBooksByClassName('2')">
 <ion-card color="explore_grade">
    <ion-card-header>
    <p style="text-align: center; padding-top: 20%;">Class 2</p>
    </ion-card-header>
 <ion-card-content>
    <!-- Add card content here! -->
  </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
 </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
 <ion-segment-button value="garde1" (click)="showBooksByClassName('3')">
 <ion-card color="explore_grade">
    <ion-card-header>
    <p style="text-align: center; padding-top: 20%;">Class 3</p>
    </ion-card-header>
 <ion-card-content>
    <!-- Add card content here! -->
    </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
 </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
 <ion-segment-button value="garde1" (click)="showBooksByClassName('6')">
    <ion-card color="explore_grade">
    <ion-card-header>
    <p style="text-align: center; padding-top: 20%;">Class 6</p>
    </ion-card-header>
 <ion-card-content>
    <!-- Add card content here! -->
    </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
 </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-col>
 
  </ion-row>

  

</ion-grid>  


   
 
<!-- This is showing tabs for the cbse grades  -->
<ion-list padding *ngSwitchCase="'mycourses'">

<ion-list *ngFor="let post of board">
 <ion-card >

    <img src="img/{{post.src}}" />
    <ion-row no-padding>
      <!--<ion-col>
        <button ion-button clear small  icon-start>
          <ion-icon name='cart'></ion-icon>
          Add to cart
        </button>
      </ion-col> -->
      <ion-col text-center>
        <button ion-button clear small  icon-start>
          {{post.Name}}
        </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col text-right>
        <button ion-button clear small  icon-start (click)="scan()">
          Scan Bar code
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
 </ion-card>

</ion-list>
```